# How can I determine which li in an ul has been clicked upon?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a quiz game in HTML/JavaScript which selects questions at random and adds the question and answer to the page (`document.getElementById, innerHTML` etc.)

I want to add a click listener so when an answer is clicked it will determine if it is correct  or not. How should I set up this listener (or listeners?) to distinguish between `li`s.

JavaScript

```
var elementQuestion = document.getElementById("question"); 
var elementAnswers = document.getElementById("answers"); 
elementQuestion.innerHTML = question[currentQuestion]; 
for(a = 0; a < answers[currentQuestion].length; a++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = answers[currentQuestion][a];
    elementAnswers.appendChild(li);
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Question -->
<p id="question"> </p>
<!-- Answer Array -->
<ul id="answers"> </ul>
```

(I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious...) Thanks

Comment: What's your relevant html?

Comment: Ah, sorry, will add that.

Comment: There's only one question, or only one element with the `id` of `question`?

Comment: There is only one element with the `id` of `question`. 

The question is selected at random and then added to the page. (From the `question[]` array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your answer, you can also add an EventListener for that:

```
elementAnswers.addEventListener("click", been_clicked, true);
```

In the callback funktion "been_clicked" you can refer to the Element
that handled the Event (here: the ul-node) as "this", and to the
Element that was clicked as "e.target":

```
function been_clicked(e) {
   alert("You clicked '" + e.target.innerHTML + "'");
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/7kSw5/ for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into the loop:

```
li.onclick=create_on_click_function(li);
```

And add a new function, that will generate onclick callback function:

```
function create_on_click_function(element){

      return function(){
            alert(element.innerHTML + ' clicked');
      }
}
```

Add appropriate parameters to determine, whether the id of the clicked `<li>` element is equal to answer id.

Comment: why do you call it "createToggleFunction" when the function it returns has nothing to do with toggeling?  where does the 'id' come from?  this won't work!

Comment: @bjelli I modified the function: 1. changed the name to meaningful 2. Added the correct parameter. 3. Checked the answer at jsfiddle. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an id to each `<li>` (like answer_0, answer_1, etc.), you can have a single listener on the `<ul>`, to since events on the list items will bubble up:

```
var elementQuestion = document.getElementById("question"); 
var elementAnswers = document.getElementById("answers"); 
elementQuestion.innerHTML = question[currentQuestion]; 
for(a = 0; a < answers[currentQuestion].length; a++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = answers[currentQuestion][a];
    li.id = "answer_" + a
    elementAnswers.appendChild(li);
}
elementAnswers.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert("Clicked on " + e.target.id);
});
```